# Convertir a int cadena de un arreglo

Tags: php, json, array

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-09", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-09", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-15", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-16", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-16", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-17", 2];

$fechaAnt="";
$repetidos=1; //agregado

for ($l=0; $l < count($dat); $l++) {  

  if($dat[$l][0]!=$fechaAnt || $fechaAnt==""){ //Si tu fecha es diferente a la anterior o es igual a vacio porque es la primera vez

    $lineas=$dat[$l][1]; //inicia lineas
    $hola[]= [$dat[$l][0],$lineas]; //Se asigna la la fecha y las lineas

   }else if($dat[$l][0]==$fechaAnt){ //si tu fecha es igual a la anterior

      $lineas=$lineas.",".$dat[$l][1]; //sigue concatenando
      $hola[$l-$repetidos][1]= $lineas; //Se asigna solo la variable $lineas
      $repetidos++;

    }
$fechaAnt=$dat[$l][0]; //Asignas valor a la fecha anterior que es la que acabas de pasar

}
```

Lo que hace es concatenar los números en caso de que la fecha se repita y al imprimir el JSON me arroja algo así

```
echo json_encode($hola); // $hola es mi variable que tiene mi arreglo 

0:["2016-11-09", "1,2"]
1:["2016-11-15", 1]
2:["2016-11-16", "1,4"]
3:["2016-11-17", 2]
```

y necesito que quede de la siguiente manera,

```
0:["2016-11-09", 1, 2]
1:["2016-11-15", 1]
2:["2016-11-16", 1, 4]
3:["2016-11-17", 2]
```

que en los valores que se concatenan le  quite las  "", 
el problema es que no se como hacerlo
Alguien que me pueda ayudar ¿?

Comment: @Marcos, cambie mi codigo pero es el mismo problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realizando la prueba en rextester, agregue la variable `$cuantos` está se encargaría de agregar nuevas posiciones al arreglo `$hola` cuando se repiten las fechas y se elimino la variable `$lineas`

```
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-09", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-09", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-15", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-16", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-16", 1];
$dat[] =  ["2016-11-17", 2];

$fechaAnt="";
$repetidos=1; //agregado

for ($l=0; $l < count($dat); $l++) {  

   if($dat[$l][0]!=$fechaAnt || $fechaAnt==""){ //Si tu fecha es diferente a la anterior o es igual a vacio porque es la primera vez

      $lineas=$dat[$l][1]; //inicia lineas
      $hola[]= [$dat[$l][0],$lineas]; //Se asigna la la fecha y las lineas
      $cuantos = 2;  //se inicia en 2 que viene siendo la 3 posición del arreglo donde quiero agregar un nuevo entero

  }else if($dat[$l][0]==$fechaAnt){ //si tu fecha es igual a la anterior

     $hola[$l-$repetidos][$cuantos]= $dat[$l][1]; //Se asigna solo la variable $lineas
     $repetidos++;
     $cuantos++;
  }
  $fechaAnt=$dat[$l][0]; //Asignas valor a la fecha anterior que es la que acabas de pasar
}
```

[Prueba de hola](http://rextester.com/SUT70088)

Answer (score 2):

Para que las `$lineas` se agreguen al arreglo, el único cambio que necesitas hacer, es modificar la línea:

```
$hola[$l-$repetidos][1]= $lineas; //Se asigna solo la variable $lineas
```

A esto:

```
$hola[$l-$repetidos][]= $dat[$l][1]; // Agregamos al arreglo la nueva "linea"
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://rextester.com/OVQEUD71091)</kbd>